# What would prevent me from selecting verticies of active object in edit mode? (v2.82 is it a bug or my ineptness)

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

I had been modelling a part by applying a mirror modifier to a box and doing extrusions and such without problems. The problem appeared shortly after adding a sphere object inside edit mode and moving that into place so the two surfaces intersect... Now the project is in some state that no matter what I do I cannot select vertices anywhere within the object in edit mode even after restarting blender.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overlays were disabled. Click on the overlay button to make selection and other things reappear.

[image]

Comment: Thank you and +1 for animating the answer.